# Question about Fibonacci sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

I proved that at Fib. $$\frac{1}{f_{n-1}f_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{f_{n-1}f_{n}}-\frac{1}{f_{n}f_{n+1}}$$

I need to prove two thing:

1.$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f_{n-1}f_{n+1}}=1$$
2.
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}f_{n+1}}=2$$

I'll glad to get help.

Thank you!

Comment: you have done sufficient hard work. Now  Telescopic Series is calling you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1.$

$$\frac1{f_{n+1}f_{n-1}}=\frac{f_{n+1}-f_{n-1}}{f_nf_{n+1}f_{n-1}}\text{  as  }f_n=f_{n+1}-f_{n-1}$$

$$\implies\frac1{f_{n+1}f_{n-1}}=\frac1{f_nf_{n-1}}-\frac1{f_nf_{n+1}} $$

Can you recognize the [Telescopic Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?

$2.$

$$\frac{f_n}{f_{n+1}f_{n-1}}=\frac{f_{n+1}-f_{n-1}}{f_{n+1}f_{n-1}}=\frac1{f_{n-1}}-\frac1{f_{n+1}}$$

Again, try to  recognize the [Telescopic Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?

Comment: But if I'm right at 2 you didn't get 2...

Comment: @YoavFridman, please pinpoint the mistake, here I'm more concerned with the mean than the end result